# Touchpad pointing but not clicking in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: touchpad

I've been facing a problem with my touchpad each time my laptop shuts down because of empty charging. It stops working altogether then it's fixed by itself.

Yesterday it stopped working entirely, so I updated the GRUB config using:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

I changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` from `"quiet splash"` TO `"i8042.reset quiet splash"`

NOW the touch-pad is only pointing without the ability to click 
I installed Mouse and Touch-pad indicator and seems everything should be working well but it's not working.

[image: Mouse Touch_pad]

My laptop is : Lenovo Thinkpad E460
The OS is : Ubuntu 16.4 - 64 bit

Comment: Do you have any other OS installed to make sure it's not simply a hardware issue? Or does a usb-connected mouse work fine?

Comment: No it's the only OS I installed , and yes if i connect an USB mouse it's work fine